# Asus laptop - what LED error codes on boot mean?

Tags: boot, asus-laptop

I have an Asus N580 laptop. When I turn it on it does not boot (no POST), black screen with no logo, fans are working, LEDs are blinking. What I want now is to understand what these LED errors mean:

- **Power LED** is ON.
- **The battery LED** is blinking white:
  two blinks and pause, then again two blinks and pause.

What I have tried to understand what these LEDs mean:

- When I disconnect LCD cable on motherboard then battery LED blinks four times then pause. This definitely means no LCD.
- When I take out memory it still blinks two times and then pause.

I could not find the meaning for Asus LED error codes anywhere on internet. Does anybody have the reference to the meaning of these Asus LED boot errors? Thanks!

Comment: Have you contacted Asus support?

Comment: Asus does not share the laptop codes publicly, these are to aid Asus repair centers only unfortunately.

Comment: @Moab, thanks. I have guessed that this info is only for Asus internal use when I could not find any code reference.

Comment: @Todd, not yet. I thought it would take more time than finding these codes myself. Now I will contact them and ask them. And then I will hopefully provide the answer here.